# Filtering a collection against a list of combinations in mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-6.0

We have a collection of users with the following class definition.

```
public class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get;set; }
    public Guid CompanyId { get;set; }
    public Guid AddressTypeId { get;set; }
    public Guid LocationId { get;set; }
    public Guid DepartmentId { get;set; }
}
```

We're trying to query a list of users with a companyId, that matches a list of LocationFilter, with the following class definition.

```
public class LocationFilter
{
    public Guid AddressTypeId { get;set; }
    public ICollection<Guid> LocationIds { get;set; }
    public ICollection<Guid> DepartmentIds { get;set; }
}
```

The querying API definition will look like this:

```
Task<List<User>> GetUserLocationList(
  Guid companyId, 
  List<LocationFilter> locationFilters);
```

I have the following Builder queries if we're querying against a single LocationFilter.

```
var companyIdFilter = Builders<User>.Filter
  .Eq(user => user.CompanyId, companyId);
var addressTypeIdFilter = Builders<User>.Filter
  .Eq(user => user.AddressTypeId, addressTypeId);
var locationIdFilter = Builders<User>.Filter
  .In(user => user.LocationId, locationIds);
var departmentIdFilter = Builders<User>.Filter
  .In(user => user.DepartmentId, departmentIds);

var andFilter = Builders<User>.Filter
  .And(
    companyIdFilter, 
    addressTypeIdFilter,
    locationIdFilter,
    departmentIdFilter);

var result = await collection.Find(andFilter).ToListAsync();
```

But how do we filter against a list of locationfilter?
Each locationfilter is it's own, it cannot intersect.
For example, all users checked against location filter A, then against location filter B etc.

How can we achieve that using builder queries?
Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `Or` to combine the location filters to find any users that matches (at least) one of the filters, e.g. (assuming that all users should be from the same company):

```
public FilterDefinition<User> BuildLocationFilter(LocationFilter locFilter)
{
    var addressTypeIdFilter = Builders<User>.Filter
      .Eq(user => user.AddressTypeId, locFilter.AddressTypeId);
    var locationIdFilter = Builders<User>.Filter
      .In(user => user.LocationId, locFilter.LocationIds);
    var departmentIdFilter = Builders<User>.Filter
      .In(user => user.DepartmentId, locFilter.DepartmentIds);
    
    var andFilter = Builders<User>.Filter
      .And(
        companyIdFilter, 
        addressTypeIdFilter,
        locationIdFilter,
        departmentIdFilter);

    return andFilter;
}

public FilterDefinition<User> BuildCompanyAndLocationFilters(
    Guid companyId, 
    IEnumerable<LocationFilter> locFilters)
{
    var locFilterDefs = 
        Builders<User>.Filter.Or(locFilters.Select(x => BuildLocationFilter(x)));
    return Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(x => CompanyId, companyId)
        & locFilterDefs;  
}
```

This retrieves all the users of the company that fulfill at least one company filter condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This works great tested it out.  Thanks again sir :)